# How to eliminate repeated data using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numbers

I listed my data to something like this. I want to eliminate the repeated data in each row. How can I do that using MATLAB?

```
13  13  13  13  38  38  38

13  13  42  0   0   0   0
```

Expected result:

```
13 38

13 42
```

Comment: Does Matlab have an abstract datatype that represents a [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))?  If so that's what I would recommend.

Comment: @mar: do you always have the same number of unique values in each row? if not you have to use cell arrays to store the result...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the function `unique`. Check out the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html).

One way of operating on each of the rows of a matrix would be to call `unique` inside a loop for each row. Obviously, you could end up with different numbers of unique elements for each row, so you may have to store the result in a `cell` array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To select unique elements from a vector, you can do:

```
a = unique(b, 'first');
```

You can find more about this function from Mathworks site [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html).

**Update**

Building on what Amro said, you could do something like this if the top and bottom aren't guaranteed to be the same length (I'm guess they aren't, since that seems like an unlikely event):

```
result = {}
for i = 1:size(a, 1)
  result{i} = unique(a(i, :), 'first');
end;
```

Comment: but i want the answer to be listed like this [13 38; 13 42] instead of a = 13, 38, 42....is it possible?

Comment: You mean if the input is a matrix? I'm not sure how that would work as you might get a different number of elements on the top and bottom, which wouldn't be a valid matrix.

Comment: sorry...i'm really not sure what i did is, in fact this is my first time using matlab. i read my simulation data file using matlab. from that data, i made a list. but, in  my list, i want those repeated data to be eliminated. should i show u my matlab program?

Comment: It might help. What are you planning on doing with the data?